# How to loop a table in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to throw the last 2 digits of the clock, I use jquery but it always fails in looping

Only one row changes, i want to change all rows.

this is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var jam = $("#jamberangkat").text();
    var datearray = jam.split(":");
    var newjam = datearray[0] + ":" + datearray[1];
    return $("#jamberangkat").text(newjam); 
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="jamberangkat" style="width:20%;">{{ $data->jam }}</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

this is my result

[image: Result]

Comment: There isn't a loop in your code at all. What do you mean?

Comment: Remember that ID's **must be unique**. Based on your screenshot I have an inkling that you are duplicating your ID throughout the table.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to iterate through all the `<td>` with the ID of `jamberangkat`. Remember that **IDs must be unique throughout the DOM**, so you will need to use a class to identify that cell that you want to change.

Most jQuery methods are actually implicit iterators, so you can simply use a callback in `$('.jamberangkat').text(<callback>)` to perform the text filtering for you for **all elements that matches the selector**. What you want in that filter is:

1. Extract the text value of the element. This is accessible as the second argument in the `.text()` method: [refer to the jQuery API documentation for `.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)
2. Split the text by `:` as you have intended
3. Keep only the first two elements (in your code I deduced you only want to keep the first and second fragment of the array). This can be done by using `.slice(0, 2)`
4. Rejoin the spliced array (which now retains only the first two elements) using `.join(':')`.

See proof-of-concept example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".jamberangkat").text(function(index, txt) {
      return txt.split(':').slice(0,2).join(':');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="jamberangkat" style="width:20%;">12:34:56</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="jamberangkat" style="width:20%;">12:34:56</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="jamberangkat" style="width:20%;">12:34:56</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="jamberangkat" style="width:20%;">12:34:56</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```